# The distribution of the sum of $k$ out of $n$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Given a list of numbers from $1$ to $n$, I select $k$ values at once (i.e. no duplicates).

After summing them up, what is the most frequent value that I am likely to get?

My intuition tells me that:

- For an even value of $n$, it should be $\dfrac{n}{2}\cdot{k}$
- For an odd value of $n$, it should be $\dfrac{n-1}{2}\cdot{k}$ and $\dfrac{n+1}{2}\cdot{k}$

Is there any simple way to prove it?

Does the distribution of the sum conform to any known pattern (e.g. normal distribution)?

Comment: If $n$ and $k$ are odd, $\frac{n}{2}\cdot k$ is _never_ achievable.  Are you asking for the average, or the most frequent value?

Comment: @Slade: Correct, sorry. I am indeed asking for the exact (most frequent) value, not the average. Thanks.

Comment: Actually shouldn't the value be $\frac{n+1}{2}k$?

Comment: @symmetricuser: Question updated for even and odd values of $n$, thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos You're missing symmetricuser's point: you're summing from _1_ to $n$, so the mean value isn't $\frac n2$, it's $\frac{n+1}2$.  Consider $n=2$ and $k=2$ to see what they're talking about.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: If we were to pick $3$ numbers from $1$ to $10$, then I would expect the most frequent sum to be $15$. For example, $4+5+6,3+5+7,2+6+7,$... Again, I'm not **stating** what the most frequent sum is, I'm just speculating it and asking for a formal proof or counterexample. In addition, I am interested in the distribution type of this sum.

Comment: @barakmanos I understand - but the _average_ value of a number from 1 to 10 isn't $5$; it's $5\frac12$.  Your formula would have the 'most common' value for choosing two numbers from 1 to 2 as being 2, when it should be 3 (your only poossible sum is 1+2).  If I chose two numbers from 1..10, I would expect the most frequent sum to be _11_, not 10.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

For every $k$-subset $A \subset [n]$ whose elements do not sum up to $\frac{n+1}{2}k$, we can create a matching to a subset $B$ as follows:
$$B = \{ i \in [n] : n-i \in A \}$$
Note that the elements of $B$ do not add up to $\frac{n+1}{2}k$ either. Also note that the sum of the elements of $A$ and the sum of the elements of $B$ average to $\frac{n+1}{2}k$. Then, we can see that every $k$-subset of $[n]$ can be paired with another $k$-subset of $[n]$ that average out to $\frac{n+1}{2}k$ or already add up to that amount. In other words, the sums of the $k$-subsets are symmetrical about $\frac{n+1}{2}k$, and so we can conclude that your intuition is correct.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac n2k$ isn't a local minimum?  This shows that the distribution is symmetric about its center, but doesn't give any guarantees that that center is a maximum.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki oh oops, I misread the question; I thought it was asking for the expected value...

Comment: If we remove the constraint "no duplicates" the claim is quite trivial, hence we just have to prove that the duplicates does not affect really much the distribution, in particular that they do not affect its symmetry at all.